# Telethon can't get chat entity anymore

Tags: telethon

I reactivated a "old" bot and get this error:

```
telethon\utils.py", line 138, in _raise_cast_fail        
    raise TypeError('Cannot cast {} to any kind of {}.'.format(
TypeError: Cannot cast coroutine to any kind of Peer.
```

After some trying... I found out that this error occures when I do whitelist chats in the functions:

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(chats=bot.get_entity(config_group),pattern='/hello'))
async def hello(event):
```

My work around is:

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/hello'))
async def hello(event):

    if int(event.chat_id) == int(config_group):
```

It works but for how long?
Im wondering if I do something wrong? (I mean at the whitelist parameter the function isnt awaited - if that is the reason) But it works one week ago so ...

Thanks if you can help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs and usernames can be passed to chats= parameters, Telethon will get entity automatically.

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat_id, pattern='/hello'))
async def hello(event):
    # do your things
```

As far as the error you got, [`get_entity`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.users.UserMethods.get_entity) returns coroutine so it must be awaited.

```
>> TypeError: Cannot cast coroutine to any kind of Peer.
```

Comment: Okay I tested.it... If I pass the id it works (for now) ... I also have a bot that work if I use ```get_entity()``` without the awaiting in ```@bot.on(...```

Its kind of strange... because why it work sometimes and sometimes not? The diffrent I found out is: The version that needs a await or an id dont find the entitywith ```get_entity()``` if I pass only the name. The other version does get also the entity by passing the name .... IN this context I talk about an name / id of a group...

Comment: probably it's just misbehaving because you're feeding data the library doesn't expect

Answer (score 2):

`get_entity` works fine what is the value of config_group can you say ?

Comment: Its the ID of the chat/group. I also tryied it with the name of the group, that sometimes works and sometimes not ... (Think because of groups with same name or somth like that. Not tested so far)

Comment: ok `get entity (config_group)` must be awaited and yeah you are right

Comment: Hmm... It's kind of strange because I take a look into my other bots... I use it everywhere this way (without await - it not even work whit an await in the event handler) But today I get the first time an error.